# Laravel request validation by groups

Tags: laravel, validation, request

So, I have a Creators table with all informations related to the creator.
This table has some nullable columns that can be filled depending on what type of creator you are.
As an example one can be an "indipendent" creator or a "company" creator. In the second case the creator will have to fill in the columns related to his company.
At the moment I am arranging it with something like this inside the Controller:

```
    public function isValid(Request $request)
    {
        $creator = //creator validation rules;
        $company = //company validation rules;
        $transfer = //another set of rules;
        if (!$request->indipendent)
            $creator = array_merge($creator, $company);
        $creator = array_merge($creator, $transfer);
        return $request->validate($creator);
    }
```

I want to however create a new CreatorRequest that validates the request.
The only method I could think of was to override the `validate()` function, but is there a way to do this by only utilizing the `rules()` function? 
Ideally I would like to have the `$creator $company` and `$transfer` inside the rules and be able to choose which groups I want validated. 
For example:

```
$request->validate(['creator', 'company']); //doesn't validate transfer
```

What is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

I say the best approach here is to break your request out into three separate request classes, and inject them using the laravel container:

```
public function isValid(CreateCreatorRequest $creator, CreateCompanyRequest $company, TransferRequest $transfer)
{
    if (!$request->indipendent)
        $creator = array_merge($creator, $company);
    $creator = array_merge($creator, $transfer);
    return $request->validate($creator);
}
```

Laravel will automatically handle passing the current request into those request classes, and you'll get your validated data as an array. The handy advantage here is you can force an interface directly against an intended action - you can apply the same `CreateCompanyRequest` in a different controller action and have a central place for all the validation rules.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#creating-form-requests